# FullPage.js 1 div be a background for all sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, css-position, fullpage.js

I was just messing around with the FullPage.js extension to see if it could help me achieve the result I want. Basically I want one div to be the background for all the sections, in my case it is not a video or image I want to keep in the background, but a threejs animation it would be a waste of resources to run the script each time. I already tried

```
 <div id="fullpage">
  <!-- id="webgl" Three js script would be loaded here --> 
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

And I tried this to style the the div where the script loaded with

```
#webgl{
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
}
```

So far only the 1st sections content will show up over the loaded script as desired but then when I scroll I get to the second section and the script is no longer visible even with the position fixed. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make background fixed,you can try `background-attachment` property,add following to the content.

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

or, have you tried put your fixed content out of the fullpage element:

```
<!-- id="webgl" Three js script would be loaded here -->
<div id="fullpage">

  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

and set the section property

```
background: transparent;
```

maybe you can have a try.

Comment: Placing it outside the div worked! It was actually specified in the documentation, the I just realized this thanks lol

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add "overflow:scroll;"